# switch in downloadHandler doesn't work R shiny

Tags: r, download, shiny, switch-statement

When I download the report it's always the PDF one. I've tested separately each one and they work so the problem comes from the switch but the problem is that I've tried some things and nothing works I don't understand why.

Here is my code:

```
library(rmarkdown)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("algo", "Selection de l'agorithme utilise pour la simulation:", choice = list("algo1", "algo2")),
  radioButtons('format', 'Document format', c('PDF', 'HTML', 'Word'), inline = TRUE),
  downloadButton("report", "Generate report")
)



server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$report <- downloadHandler(
    filename = switch(input$format,
                      "Word" = function() {
                        paste("reportHtml-", Sys.Date(), ".docx", sep="")
                      }, 
                      "PDF" = function() {
                        paste("reportPDF-", Sys.Date(), ".pdf", sep="")
                      },
                      "Word" = function() {
                        paste("reportHtml-", Sys.Date(), ".html", sep="")
                      }
    ),

    content =  switch(input$format,
                      "Word" = function(file1) {

                        report <- file.path("C:/R_sources/test/reportWord.Rmd")
                        params <- list(n = input$algo)
                        rmarkdown::render(report, output_file = file1,
                                          params = params,
                                          envir = new.env(parent = globalenv())
                        )
                      },

                      "PDF" = function(file2) {

                        report <- file.path("C:/R_sources/test/reportPdf.Rmd")
                        params <- list(n = input$algo)
                        rmarkdown::render(report, output_file = file2,
                                          params = params,
                                          envir = new.env(parent = globalenv())
                        )
                      },

                      "Word" = function(file3) {

                        report <- file.path("C:/R_sources/test/reportWord.Rmd")
                        params <- list(n = input$algo)
                        rmarkdown::render(report, output_file = file3,
                                          params = params,
                                          envir = new.env(parent = globalenv())
                        )
                      }
    )
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: In the code there are two "Word" case but anyway it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.0.5/downloadHandler.html,

> filename: A string of the filename...or a function that returns such a string. (Reactive values and functions may be used from this function.)

So you should be aiming to pass a function to the `filename` parameter.

What is happening in your code is the `downloadHelper` gets evaluated and run when it's loaded, at which point `input$format` is set to "PDF" as that's the initial value. So the switch statement gets evaluated and `filename` always has PDF function bound to it.

What you should be doing is setting a function, and use a switch statement inside there. Likewise for `content`. So it should be something like:

```
library(rmarkdown)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("algo", "Selection de l'agorithme utilise pour la simulation:", choice = list("algo1", "algo2")),
  radioButtons('format', 'Document format', c('PDF', 'HTML', 'Word'), inline = TRUE),
  downloadButton("report", "Generate report")
)



server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$report <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      switch(input$format,
        Word = paste("reportHtml-", Sys.Date(), ".docx", sep=""), 
        PDF = paste("reportPDF-", Sys.Date(), ".pdf", sep=""),
        HTML = paste("reportHtml-", Sys.Date(), ".html", sep="")
        )
      },

    content = function(file) {
      switch(input$format,
        Word = {
          report <- file.path("C:/R_sources/test/reportWord.Rmd")
          params <- list(n = input$algo)
          rmarkdown::render(report, output_file = file,
                            params = params,
                            envir = new.env(parent = globalenv())
                            )
        },
        PDF = {
          report <- file.path("C:/R_sources/test/reportPdf.Rmd")
          params <- list(n = input$algo)
          rmarkdown::render(report, output_file = file,
                            params = params,
                            envir = new.env(parent = globalenv())
                            )
        },
        HTML = {
          report <- file.path("C:/R_sources/test/reportHtml.Rmd")
          params <- list(n = input$algo)
          rmarkdown::render(report, output_file = file,
                            params = params,
                            envir = new.env(parent = globalenv())
                            )
        }
      )
    }


  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks, great to hear :) You can mark my answer as Accepted if you feel your question is answered

Comment: How can I do that haha ?